# 2017 Volt misfire during open loop

Tags: chevrolet, misfire, volt

2017 Volt
Engine misfires while in open loop. No DTC, so dealerships cannot diagnose. Their mechanic experienced the misfire on test drive. Intermittent miss: similar to a failing plug wire.
Question: Does the cpu record pending dtc's while in open loop?

Comment: In Skoda 2006 when the engine get intermittent missfire, it shuts down that cylinder (cuts of fuel) until I park and clear it with an OBD scanner.

Comment: Maybe put a COP secondary probe in place and check the waveform while it misfires. would probably be the easiest place to start. or warranty the engine...